# Schedule backup on Google App Engine

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine

I am trying to use the schedule backup mechanism from GAE but keep getting an error message than the cron.xml has a syntax error. The same error message appears using Google's samples.

I am using sdk 1.7.0

### I. cron.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?name=BackupToCloud&kind=LogTitle&kind=EventLog&filesystem=gs&gs_bucket_name=whitsend</url>
    <description>My Daily Backup</description>
    <schedule>every 12 hours</schedule>
    <target>ah-builtin-python-bundle</target>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

### II. cron.xsd (the one provided by default)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="cronentries" type="cronentries-Type"/>

  <xs:complexType name="cronentries-Type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="cron-Type" name="cron" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="cron-Type">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="url"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="schedule"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="timezone" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="target-Type" name="target" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="target-Type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[a-z\d\-]{1,100}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

### III. The error message

"The reference to entity "kind" must end with the ';' delimiter." I am getting the same error message when checking the xml validity using a on-line xml validator.

==> Did someone face the same issue and if so how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the & using `&amp;` read: replace & in the url element with `&amp;`

Comment: The weird thing though is that the call to the appcfg.sh did not request my userid / password. Do you think it could be a security issue ?./appcfg.sh update_cron

Comment: It saves it in a cookie that will expire, you can override this by using --no_cookie or use the oauth2 flag.

Comment: Shay, you are just a superstar ! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

We (Streak.com) open sourced a tool that does automated backups as well as automated pushes of logs and datastore data into bigquery. The project is here: https://github.com/StreakYC/mache

Comment: Hi Aloo, thanks a lot for making this open source. While reading the doc, I see the usage for exporting the logs. Do you mean the same framework can be used for backup ? Also, is there any functionality for restoring data ? Once again thanks a lot for making this code open source, that's awesome !